# Re.sub in python (remove last _)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string such as:

```
string="lcl|NC_011588.1_cds_YP_002321424.1_1"
```

and I would like to keep only: `"YP_002321424.1"`

So I tried :

```
string=re.sub(".*_cds_","",string)
string=re.sub("_\d","",string)
```

Does someone have an idea? 
But the first `_` is removed to

Note: The number can change (they are not fixed).

Comment: Why not to use `str.split` instead? It should be enough for your case.

Comment: if you wish to continue your route, just edit your regex to ```".*_cds"```

Comment: Please, look, the last part (_1) is also removed

Comment: With `r"_\d$"` perhaps?

Comment: The following would work `result = re.search(r'cds_(.*)_', string).group(1)`. It works because `.*` is not greedy, aka it matches as much as possible. (opposed to `.*?` which makes a match as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

"Ordinary" split, as proposed in the other answer, is not enough,
because you also want to strip the trailing `_1`, so the part to capture
should end after a dot and digit.

Try the following pattern:

```
(?<=_cds_)\w+\.\d
```

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/U2QsFH/1

Answer (score -1):

Don't bother with regexes, a simple

```
string.split('_cds_')[1]
```

will be enough

Comment: That wouldn't remove the `_1` at the end.

Comment: Not really, if you have more then one occurrence of the pattern, it will cause issues.

Comment: Yes, forgot about the _1 at the end. However the user made no mention of several occurences, so I implied there was only one